# get error when want POST something to api{detail: "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing."}

Tags: javascript, python, django

when i want to POST some thing to API ,
i get this error :  CSRF TOKEN , but i don't have CSRF Token in django , i want POST without CSRF token
i can POST with Postman but when i want post it by js , i get error that i said in first
how can i do?

```
    let edit_data = {
        user_id: "1",
        company: "rahaaaa",
        description: "12343234234",
        first_name: "324234234234312sd",
        id_number: "122222",
        last_name: "32423dqwe32",
    }
    let c = JSON.stringify(edit_data)
    console.log(c);



    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/postCustomer/", {
        headers: { 
            "Content-Type": "application/json",     
        },

        method: "POST",
        body:c,




    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

when i want to POST some thing to API ,
i get this error :  CSRF TOKEN , but i don't have CSRF Token in django , i want POST without CSRF token
how can i do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If the server requires a csrf token, there’s nothing you can do in the client side code to fix that except send a csrf token.  The fix (and the crux of the question) lie in the server code which you haven’t posted.

Answer (score 0):

Let your post-view method know, that you don't want to validate the CSRF token.

You can use the following decorator if you are using function-based views.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
@csrf_exempt
def my_view(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello world')
```

If you are using class-based views then

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views import View
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
 
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
class YourViewName(View):
    # Your Post Method
    def post(self, request):
        return HttpResponse('OK')
```